# ERROR in NgSemanticModule is not an NgModule Angular cli

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-2.0, typescript

estoy implementando ngsemantic y me encontre con el siguiente error ERROR in NgSemanticModule is not an NgModule.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi package.json

```js
{
  "name": "SaveBPM",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.72",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.1",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema conocido, que puedes ver en https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic/issues/149

Hay una solicitud de pull abierta: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic/pull/178

Pero el proyecto parece un poco estancado.